# Remove lines which not consist / filter csv flle

Tags: powershell

I have csv files with wsus raport ( there are server names )
I have also txt file with server names which are in my scope.

I would like remove entry from my csv files if not match txt files.

I found solution how to to something appositive ( keep lines if match)

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\temp\wsus.csv'
$scope = Get-Content C:\Temp\windows_server.txt
foreach ($Pattern in $scope)
{
(Get-Content $SourceFile) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $Pattern } | Set-Content $SourceFile
}
```

I was hopping that I change -notmatch to -match and it will work but doesn't.

Best Regards,
Krzysztof

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to write it exactly the other way round:

```
Get-Content $sourceFile | where {
    foreach($pattern in $scope) {
        if ($_ -match $pattern) {
            return $true
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be using `Select-String`:

```
Get-Content $sourceFile | Select-String -Pattern $scope
```

Also, when working with CSV, you should consider using the appropriate cmdlets (like `Import-Csv`).

Comment: Thank you very much :) Both your solution works I have just save to another file like wsus1.cvs because I got message that file is bussy but anyway thank you.

that solve my issue: Get-Content $sourceFile | Select-String -Pattern $scope | Set-Content C:\temp\wsus2.csv

now need to learn how to bring back my headers from csv :)

Best Ragards, Krzysztof

Comment: @19Kris88 Yea sorry my bad, of course you can't both read and write the same file in the same pipeline, haha. Well and the headers issue is exactly why you'd use Import/Export-Csv for this, but since I don't know what your patterns look like, I can't tell you how that would look exactly, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wsus.csv looks anything like this:

```
Server,Something you need to know,Something you want to forget
Srv01,Main storage,blahblah
Srv02,Mail server,more blah
```

and your windows_server.txt simply holds servernames, each on a separate line, then you could do this:

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\temp\wsus.csv'
$scope      = Get-Content C:\Temp\windows_server.txt
$csv        = Import-Csv -Path $SourceFile | Where-Object {$scope -contains $_.Server }
# now export the scoped csv (I'd suggest to a new file, but you can overwrite the $SourceFile if you must)
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\ScopedWsus.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```